# Perl interpreting following variable declaration

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, hash

Hi all I have simple newbie question on perl. I am looking at someone's perl code and he has some variable declarations as follows:

```
my $OutputFiles=[];
$OutputFiles = 
[
 { FID => 789133, TAGE => "BRWSGF_05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
 { FID => 789134, TAGE => "BRWSGF_W05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' }, 
 { FID => 789135, TAGE => "BRWSGF_E05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
];
```

It seems to be some sort of array of hash but the variable declaration of `$OutputFiles` is not like that of an array so I am confused. Please let me know what is the variable `$OutputFiles` supposed to be and how can one manipulate such a variable. 
Again I admit frankly that I am a rank Perl newbie.

Comment: http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_00.html

Comment: If you are going to work with Perl, it's important to learn how to recognize, and create arrays and hashes and scalars, AND convert them to/from references. That's the basis for slinging a lot of data around efficiently.

Comment: I would say that he doesn't know much more about Perl than you. There is no reason to set `$OutputFiles` to an anonymous array **twice**. You could remove the first line, and add a `my` to the front of the other one.

Answer (score 5):

`[]` creates an *array reference*, which is a scalar.

```
my $foo = [1, 2, 3];
```

Gives the same value of `$foo` as:

```
my @bar = (1, 2, 3);
my $foo = \@bar;
```

See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more details.

Comment: i see so it is actually an array of hash but expressed as a array reference right?

Comment: Technically it is a reference to an array of references to hashes. But your understanding is essentially correct.

Comment: got you thanks to both of you for that clarification. One more request can anyone please show me a short example of how I might access say each individual hash value by its key from the variable `$OutputFiles`

Comment: actually ignore the above request saw what I wanted below

Answer (score 0):

$OutputFiles is an array reference, like Quentin's answer explained. You're also right that it is an array of hashes, but you can also think of it as an array of hash references. Here's how you can access the data:

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $OutputFiles=[];
$OutputFiles = [
                { FID => 789133, TAGE => "BRWSGF_05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
                { FID => 789134, TAGE => "BRWSGF_W05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
                { FID => 789135, TAGE => "BRWSGF_E05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
               ];
my ($FID, $TAGE, $nfiles, $Suffix);

for my $hash_ref ( @$OutputFiles ) {
    $FID = $hash_ref->{FID};
    $TAGE = $hash_ref->{TAGE};
    $nfiles = $hash_ref->{nfiles};
    $Suffix = $hash_ref->{Suffix};
    print "FID: $FID TAGE: $TAGE nfiles: $nfiles: Suffix: $Suffix\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Quentin, it is array reference containing hashes, I am adding some small things how you can derefernce it & access the specific key from it as it contain hashes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $OutputFiles=[];
$OutputFiles =
[
 { FID => 789133, TAGE => "BRWSGF_05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
 { FID => 789134, TAGE => "BRWSGF_W05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
 { FID => 789135, TAGE => "BRWSGF_E05K", nfiles => 1, Suffix => 'jpg' },
];

my @output = @{$OutputFiles}; #dereference the array ref
print Dumper(@output );

print Dumper(@{$OutputFiles}[0]->{FID}); # accessing the specific key
```